# Hexadecimal converter using a switch statement

Tags: java

I need some help improving my code and wondering if I there is a better way to do the following:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(node.length() + 8);
        for (int i=0, n=node.length(); i<n; i++) {
            char c = node.charAt(i);
            String hexadecimal = "";
            switch (c) {
                case '"': hexadecimal = "\\22"; break;
                case '&': hexadecimal = "\\26"; break;
                case '\'': hexadecimal = "\\27"; break;
                case '/':  hexadecimal = "\\2f"; break;
                case ':': hexadecimal = "\\3a"; break;
                case '<': hexadecimal = "\\3c"; break;
                case '>': hexadecimal = "\\3e"; break;
                case '@': hexadecimal ="\\40"; break;
                case '\\':hexadecimal = "\\5c"; break;
                default: {
                    if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                        hexadecimal = "\\20";
                    }else if(c > 127){
                        hexadecimal = "\\" + Integer.toHexString(c) + "\\";
                    }
                    else {
                        hexadecimal = String.valueOf(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            buf.append(hexadecimal);
        }
        return buf.toString();
```

I don't like how there is a `switch` statement which just sets a variable (`hexadecimal`) based on what the case is. I feel there is a better way to do this, such as by using a hash-map. I need the code to be flexible so that adding new characters and setting the hexadecimal is easy.

Comment: I'm not that versed in Java but isn't toHexString('#') == 22?  So do you need the switch at all?

Comment: @dreza I'm assuming the formatting of "\22" is important. In which case `Integer.toHexString('#')` would get messy. But definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 29):

A hash map is often a good idea for avoiding switch statements. It can be used in combination with the Strategy and Abstract Factory patterns, [such](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13347/14561) [as](http://www.tomasmalmsten.com/2011/01/create-factory-strategies-ifs/) [in](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/10/refactoring-a-switch-statement/) [these](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/136) [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9942/Refactoring-to-Patterns-Factory-and-Strategy-Patte).

However, the Strategy Pattern is overkill for your problem. A simple hashmap would look like this

```
Map<Character, String> hexMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
hexMap.put('\"', "\\22");
hexMap.put('\n', "\\20");
// puts more stuff in map...

 for (int i=0, n=node.length(); i<n; i++) {
     char c = node.charAt(i);
     buf.append(hexMap.get(c));
 }
```

But a quick googling of "java character to hexadecimal" produces [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863353/830988) [results](http://jovialjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/hex-to-ascii-conversion-in-java.html). My favorite is

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(node.length() + 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < node.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = node.charAt(i);
        buf.append(String.format("\\%1$x", (ch & 0xFFFF)));
    }

return buf.toString();
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to say, don't use magic numbers. I have no clue what the frack that 8 is doing in your program nor do I have to patience to try to deduce.